# Pseudo Van der Waals gases

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

In college, when deriving the Langmuir isotherm for gas-solid adsorption, it implied equalling the chemical potentials for a certain compound in the gas and the interphase, and when dealing with the volume for the interphase, my professor proposed a modified version of the Van der Waals state equation, what he called the "pseudo Van der Waals gas state equation":

$$V\cdot (p+q) = RT$$

Where V is the volume, $p$ the pressure, $R$ the gas constant, $T$ the temperature, and $q$ a correction term to account for the adsorbate cohesion. He argued that the interphase was something similar to a very condensed gas, so that equation of state was valid. Indeed, he obtained correctly the Langmuir isotherm, that later was derived using the kinetic approach.

However, I have been reading a lot of books and articles looking for that "pseudo Van der Waals gas", and I haven´t found anything similar. I guess the approximation is just to neglect the excluded volume, but I am not sure whether my professor was right or he took some license by himself.

Comment: Both equations are just approximations.  An approximation is "valid" to use if it gets a result that's useful within some error margin over some range of values.  I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: My question was if the term "pseudo Van der Waals gas" is actually used or not, because I didn´t find it in the literature, and the same goes for its state equation.

Comment: Sometimes professors may introduce in a lecture terms and equations that do not exist in the literature. Assuming that they master the subject matter and that the term/equation works, where is the problem? You could ask your prof if there is any literature reference. If there is not, you may realize the advantage of having a good teacher instead of a standard video repeating what can be found in a book.